# What Sound (onomatopoeia) does a launching Rocket make?

Tags: single-word-requests, onomatopoeia

I searched all the internet and comics but couldn't find any onomatopoeia for Rocket blasting into space.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is too localised. English doesn't have "onomatopoeic" words suitable for every sound one can imagine. The sound of a rocket lift-off is a "[deafening/thunderous] roar", but in practice hardly anyone is going to hear it *directly* from nearby anyway - they'll just hear a low-pitched rumbling coming from a loudspeaker, or far away in the distance.

Comment: If it's writing inspiration you're looking for, check out how rockets from [hobby](http://rocketdungeon.blogspot.com/p/featured-sport-rocketry-stuff.html) to [space](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnoNITE-CLc) sound and are described.

Comment: SHSHSHSHSHSHSHShShShShShShshshshshshshhhshhhshhhshhhshhhshhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you can capture the sound with a single onomatopoeia. (If it's possible, you can probably find the word [here](http://www.writtensound.com/index.php).)

Penn Jillette wrote perhaps the [best-ever description](http://symftr.tumblr.com/post/5987695109/nasas-successful-quantifying-of-comedy-timing-by-penn) of a Space Shuttle launch, which includes this paragraph:

> Right as you say the word “noise” in your head, right as those
>   synapses connect, you get hit in the chest. You don’t exactly hear it
>   at first, it almost knocks you over. It’s the loudest most wonderful
>   sound you’ve ever heard. Megadeth’s double bass drum Quaalude thunder
>   sounds like the Preservation Hall Jazz Band’s tasteful
>   twenty-two-incher next to this. You can’t really hear it. It’s too
>   loud to hear. It’s wonderful, deep and low. It’s the bottom. For a
>   bass player or a drummer nothing could give more joy. It’s a squealy
>   lead guitar player’s worst nightmare. Pete Townshend said that music
>   should be loud enough that you can’t think of anything else, but it
>   took an explosion to make him deaf. This is a real explosion and it’s
>   controlled and it’s doing nothing but good and it makes your
>   unbuttoned shirt flap around your arms. It’s beyond sound, it’s wind.
>   It’s a man-made hurricane. It’s a baseball bat in the chest. It’s so
>   loud. It’s so loud you can’t even call it loud. You start cheering.
>   You start yelling. You start crying. You are yelling from the depth of
>   your little lizard brain. You’re yelling because stinkin’ animals have
>   done this. You know the alligators are cheering and the birds and the
>   Good Sams and every living thing on the planet is cheering. We’re all
>   cheering together because Earth animals are going into space. You can
>   feel your throat getting raw, but you can’t hear yourself scream
>   because the shuttle is so stinkin’ goddamn loud. The ground shakes and
>   it’s loud. Warfare could be louder, but this is the loudest totally
>   good thing you will ever hear. The loudest good thing you will ever
>   feel.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is an onomatopoeia-style (onomatopaedic?) word for it, because it's such a long, sustained sound.  It's a rumbling roar, so maybe the RRRR sound is what you're looking for, but there's a lot of crackling, too...

Comment: The adjectival form of *onomatopoeia* is *onomatopoeic*.

Comment: I would be seriously worried if I heard any "crackling" during take-off. They don't use logs for rocket fuel!

Comment: Rumble and roar are onomatopoeic.

Answer (score 1):

Rockets make a *rumbling* sound as they prepare for takeoff, followed by a *roaring* sound during takeoff, followed by a *whooshing* around much later.

Comment: Don't forget the sonic *boom* when it passes the speed of sound.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the rocket. Something like the space shuttle would be a prolonged roar. Something like a model rocket would go off with a "whoosh" and a bottle rocket a "fwee" although with the last, it's because they're designed to whistle.